# Workaround for setting non-constant value to an attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes

Suppose I have an attribute capable to be set to a System.Object say:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class MyAttrAttribute : Attribute {
  public object ThisOne { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to get the same result of this (that doesn't compile):

```
class AttrTarget {
  [MyAttr(ThisOne = new MyClass())]
  public MyClass Thing { get; set; }
}
```

There's a way to achieve the same result without using reflection?

Comment: You cannot do this with attributes. Attribute values must be KNOWN at compile time.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 ...or must be *retrievable* from constant values known at compile time; for example, some of the inbuilt attributes support inheritance for things like translation - but the "key" is constant, even if the value observed can vary at runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There might be better way to achieve it?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 I known this, in fact this is the object of the question -> a workaround

Comment: @SWeko I'm designing a new feature for an API of an open source lib; I've already supplied two standard initialization techniques for properties that library users (developers) could employ. Because that new feature use an existing attribute base class (already in use), I was wondering to extend the use of such attribute. I've already provided two ways to initialize such member that in the example is  MyClass::Thing. Just looking for alternative way to do the same thing; this is done by not forcing developers to a particular way of initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cws2s9d.aspx) attribute for example has a [`Type, String` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx59291k.aspx). This can be used to create an instance e.g. for desired time span or a desired color:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00:03")]
public TimeSpan Timeout {get; set;}

[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Red")]
public Color HighlightColor {get; set;}
```

So maybe this kind of creating attribute values helps you to get an idea on how to solve your problem.

Comment: +1 @Oliver, thank you for this thought; this how I solve a similar problem here (http://goo.gl/dssQK) and the question in fact was about an extension that I recently finished coding. I will consider to extend this pattern also for the new feature...

Answer (score 2):

Attributes simply aren't suited to that scenario. Using reflection *generally* won't really solve the problem, as there is no guarantee that the values assigned will be preserved between calls to inspect the attributes.

Comment: +1, ok -> I'm also getting to this conclusion... I've to agree

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is how attributes are created - they use compile time constants as parameters. But there is no restriction as to code that is executed in such attributes constructor so the workaround is to inherit form attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class MyClassMyAttrAttribute:MyAttrAttribute 
{
    MyClassMyAttrAttribute()
    {
        ThisOne = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

and use that one:

```
 [MyClassMyAttr]
 public MyClass Thing { get; set; }
```

and by the goodness of polimorfizm if you ask for `MyAttrAttribute` you will get instance of `MyClassMyAttrAttribute`.

Comment: The issue, though, is that the duration of `ThisOne` is unpredictable; you aren't guaranteed to keep getting back the same `MyClassMyAttrAttribute` instance every time you look for it, so the only thing you can rely on is the default values of the instance - which aren't usually very interesting.

Comment: The only usage of such thing in attribute is for information purposes only. I would not allow `MyClass` to hold any state that is modifiable during program execution. I use this for set of my `static readonly` fields that are in fact constants but just not compile time constant.

Comment: +1 @Rafal thanks for reply; this is clear to me. In fact I do provide such way of initialization. Maybe I was asking for an impossible real alternative to something that simply can't exist by C# design.