# How to provide a reference to a member field in an attribute?

Tags: c#

This is a made up example so don't yell at me that this is a bad design :)

Suppose I have:

```
class UserInfo
{
    SomeType1 member1;

    SomeType2 member2;

    SomeType3 member3;


    Guid idInDB1;

    Guid idInDB2;
}
```

Each member is saved either in DB1 or in DB2 (not both), and for each member I would like to provide an attribute which would point to the variable containing the DB id. Something like:

```
[DBReference(idInDB1)]
```

It this possible?

Comment: Attributes are metadata, they live on the definition of the type or a member, no the content of it. By definition, you must be able to get the values in the attribute by just knowing the type of member it is used on, not the actual instance. That being the case, you have no way of linking this attribute to actual data. What you can do is specify the database name as string or use an enum.

Comment: Attribute values must be compile time constants, meaning they most be known at compile-time as they are accounted as metadata. You can look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230414/c-workaround-for-setting-non-constant-value-to-an-attribute) for some hacky workarounds, which i wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I want to provide a reference to the variable, not it's value

Comment: A variable isn't a compile-time constant. That's why you can't use it. As a side note, you're trying to pass a `GUID` which is a `struct`, hence it is copied by-value, not by-reference.

Comment: Why not put the attribute on the property instead of the class?

Answer (score 0):

Since `Guid`s can't be compile time constants, it is easier to use `string`, and cast it to a `Guid` in your attribute.

Consider something like this:

```
public class DBReferenceAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DBReferenceAttribute(string guid)
    {
        this.Guid = new Guid(guid);
    }

    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

class UserInfo
{
    [DBReference(idInDB1)]
    string member1;

    string member2;

    string member3;


    const string idInDB1 = "000";
}
```

Comment: How should I define the DBReference constructor?

Comment: Note that idInDB1 isn't a constant, I only know it at runtime

Comment: @Shmoopy: It is not possible to use non-constant values. Either you have to map it inside the attribute, or come up with something else.